# W3 total cache plugin

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache

Is it necessary do setting after installing W3 total cache plugin Or default setting working fine with the current application?

I have done this due to I am using divi builder for pages creation and content updating sometimes content is reverting to previous. I thought its a cache problem.

Please advice.

Comment: I think default settings will be file with current applications, but in case of any changes you have to flush cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a better practice to flush the cache when using WordPress based builders in dev environment. Deactivate it while modifying complex layouts in builders and then reactivate the plugin.

This approach should work fine with your case.

Note: This is not just the case with W3 Total Cache plugin, the approach can be used for any type of cache based plugin.

I hope this helps!